# Calculate euclidean distance from dicts (sklearn)

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance

I have two `dictionaries` already calculated in my code, which look like this:

```
X = {'a': 10, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, ...}
Y = {'a': 8, 'c': 3, 'e': 8, ...}
```

Actually they contain words from wiki texts, but this should serve to show what I mean. They don't necessarily contain the same keys.

Initially I wanted to use `sklearn`'s pairwise metric like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

obama = wiki[wiki['name'] == 'Barack Obama']['tf_idf'][0]
biden = wiki[wiki['name'] == 'Joe Biden']['tf_idf'][0]

obama_biden_distance = pairwise_distances(obama, biden, metric='euclidean', n_jobs=2)[0][0]
```

However, this gives an error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-7ff03bd40683> in <module>()
      6 biden = wiki[wiki['name'] == 'Joe Biden']['tf_idf'][0]
      7 
----> 8 obama_biden_distance = pairwise_distances(obama, biden, metric='euclidean', n_jobs=2)[0][0]

/home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/coursera_ml_clustering_and_retrieval/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1205         func = partial(distance.cdist, metric=metric, **kwds)
   1206 
-> 1207     return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1208 
   1209 

/home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/coursera_ml_clustering_and_retrieval/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1058     ret = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=0)(
   1059         fd(X, Y[s], **kwds)
-> 1060         for s in gen_even_slices(Y.shape[0], n_jobs))
   1061 
   1062     return np.hstack(ret)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

To me this reads like something is trying to access the `shape` attribute, which a `dict` doesn't have. I guess it needs `numpy` arrays. How can I transform the dictionaries, so that the `sklearn` function will compute the correct distance, assuming `0` values, if a dictionary does not have a certain key, which the other dictionary has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just do it directly from your sparse representation?

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: Y = {'a': 8, 'c':3,'e':8}

In [3]: X = {'a':10, 'b':3, 'c':5}

In [4]: math.sqrt(sum((X.get(d,0) - Y.get(d,0))**2 for d in set(X) | set(Y)))
Out[4]: 9.0
```

Comment: There are over 500k data points and I wanted to let sklearn do the heavy lifting. Also in each array there need to be zeros for non existing keys, otherwise the euclidean distance is wrong.

Comment: @Zelphir Whoops! You're right. Hmmm, use cosine distance? Heh. But actually, you can still modify it so that it works by using `get` method with a default value.

Comment: @Zelphir Along with set union instead of intersection. I've used the same approach with large vocabularies and corpora of many documents before and it was reasonably fast.

Comment: I'll give it a try : ) and see if runtime is acceptable.

Comment: Wow your edit makes your code much smarter than mine! I'll try that too.

Comment: I used your version. I had one with try catch block (trying to access the key rather than asking if it's there - at least that I did) and I even used the `get` method, but only for the `Y`. I could try to recreate my version, it was very naive, but also not as nice as your version, so I don't know if that would add any value to the whole SO question.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by creating a list with all the keys of your dictionaries (it is important to note that this list has to be sorted):

```
X = {'a': 10, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
Y = {'a': 8, 'c': 3, 'e': 8}
data = [X, Y]
words = sorted(list(reduce(set.union, map(set, data))))
```

This works fine in Python 2, but if you are using Python 3 you'll need to add the sentence `from functools import reduce` (thanks to @Zelphir for spotting this). If you don't wish to import the `functools` module you can replace the last line of the snippet above by the following code:

```
words = set(data[0])
for d in data[1:]:
    words = words | set(d)
words = sorted(list(words))
```

Whatever it is the method you choose, the list `words` makes it possible to set-up a matrix in which each row corresponds to a dictionary (a sample) and the values of those dictionaries (features) are placed in the column corresponding to its key.

```
feats = zip(*[[d.get(w, 0) for d in data] for w in words])
```

This matrix can be passed to scikit's function `pairwise_distance`:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances as pd
dist = pd(feats, metric='euclidean')
```

The following interactive session demonstrates how it works:

```
In [227]: words
Out[227]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']

In [228]: feats
Out[228]: [(10, 3, 5, 0), (8, 0, 3, 8)]

In [229]: dist
Out[229]: 
array([[ 0.,  9.],
       [ 9.,  0.]])
```

Finally, you could wrap the code above into a function to compute the pairwise distance of any number of dictionaries:

```
def my_func(data, metric='euclidean'):
    words = set(data[0])
    for d in data[1:]:
        words = words | set(d)
    words = sorted(list(words))
    feats = zip(*[[d.get(w, 0) for d in data] for w in words])
    return pd(feats, metric=metric)
```

I have avoided the call to `reduce` in order for the wrapper to work across versions.

Demo:

```
In [237]: W = {'w': 1}

In [238]: Z = {'z': 1}

In [239]: my_func((X, Y, W, Z), 'cityblock')
Out[239]: 
array([[  0.,  15.,  19.,  19.],
       [ 15.,   0.,  20.,  20.],
       [ 19.,  20.,   0.,   2.],
       [ 19.,  20.,   2.,   0.]])
```

Comment: Also one should note that `reduce` needs to be imported from `functools`.

Comment: One should note that `reduce` needs to be imported from `functools`.

Earlier I forgot to rename the function and accidently ran the other function twice, which led me to believe the function in your answer works for me just the same as the other one in the accepted answer. However, when I changed the name and tried again I ran into some issues and I couldn't get your function to run : / Maybe I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Why do you think that `reduce()` needs to be imported from `functools`? The only import sentence in my code is `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances as pd` (by the way, in your question you mentioned that you wished to use it to compute the pairwise distances). The other functions are either built-in functions, namely `reduce()`, `map()`, `list()`, `set()`, `zip()` and `sorted()`, or built-in class methods such as `set.union()` and `dict.get()`. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce to convince yourself...

Comment: No offense, but it is the year 2016 ; ) I switched to Python 3 years ago. I am not using Python 2 and try to avoid it whenever possible. In Python 3 `reduce` was moved to `functools`, because many people misused it. As it is now, `sum` is available without imports, so people don't fall into the trap of using `reduce` to calculate a sum anymore. At least that's the explanation I read somewhere for `reduce` having been moved.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! :(  I haven't moved to version 3 yet and I unconsciously think that Python 2 is still deemed as the default by most people. I will edit my answer and replace the call to `reduce` by a `for` loop in order for the code to work across versions. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd want to use `X.get(search_string,0)`, which would output the value or 0 if not found.  If you have a lot of search strings you could do `[X.get(s,0) for s in list_of_strings]` which will push a list of output.